# TYPO3 8.7: findByEmail function of frontenduserrepository returns null

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

In my `module` of my custom Extension I'm trying to change the db value of a `fe_user`. In fact I'm trying to change the email and the username.
But when I use the given TYPO3 FrontendUserRepo the function `findByEmail` returns `null`. The Email `$_POST['email']` is passed correctly and I tried hardcoding a valid email as well, it didn't work.

In Controller:

Imports:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser;
```

Injection of `FrontendUserRepo` as attribute of class:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $frontendUserRepository;
```

...

In action:

```
$frontendUser =  $this->frontendUserRepository->findByEmail($_POST['email_old']);
$frontendUser->setUsername($_POST['email']);
$frontendUser->setEmail($_POST['email']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for this issue could be:

```
$querySettings = $this->FrontendUserRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
       // don't add the pid constraint
       $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
       $this->FrontendUserRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

in this case you didn't need a second storage pid

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because the storagePid hasn't been set to the folder with the frontend users. Set the storagePid for your extension to the folder with the frontend users. This can be done in TypoScript using: `module.tx_yourextension.persistence.storagePid = ...`

If your users are in a different folder than the rest of the records used by the extensions, you can set multiple uids comma separated. If you create new records you will need to set which uid each record type should be saved:

```
module.tx_yourextensions.persistence {
  storagePid = [uid1],[uid2]
  Vendor\YourExtension\Domain\Model\YourModel {
    newRecordStoragePid = [uid1]
  }
  TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
    newRecordStoragePid = [uid2]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I set the storagePid as you suggested, the rest of my module breaks. Of course I used `module`.tx_yourextension.persistence.storagePid = instead of `plugin`.txyourext.....

Comment: I've edited my answer to include information about multiple storage folders.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the object after setting the attribute.
Here is a way to do this :

```
$frontendUserRepository->update($frontendUser);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but did you even read my question? I don't have an object because the method that should return one returns null instead.